# Why does my QuantLib Python 'ql.calendar' code fail with 'TypeError: UnitedStates.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'm'' error?

Tags: python, quantlib

When I am learning the python version of QuantLib, the first program failed. I am just trying to use the `ql.calendar`. No matter I write `calendar = ql.UnitedStates()` or `calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE)`, I won't work.
In the first way, it will show: TypeError: UnitedStates.**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'm'.

Here is my code:

```
import QuantLib as ql
date = ql.Date(2,6,2023)

calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
date1 = ql.Date(1,6,2023)
date2 = ql.Date(1,6,2024)
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Monthly)
schedual = ql.Schedule(date1,date2,tenor,calendar,ql.Following,
                       ql.Following,ql.DateGeneration.Forward, False)
print(schedual)
```

I use the conda environment, with the , and install QuantLib through it, everything seems to work well when I am testing the basic functions, but calendar seems the only that failed. Here is all the packages in this environment:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
blas                      1.0                         mkl
boost-cpp                 1.78.0               h5b4e17d_0    conda-forge
bottleneck                1.3.5           py311h5bb9823_0
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2023.5.7             h56e8100_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         h59b6b97_46319
libffi                    3.4.4                hd77b12b_0
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2023.1.0         h8bd8f75_46356
mkl-service               2.4.0           py311h2bbff1b_1
mkl_fft                   1.3.6           py311hf62ec03_1
mkl_random                1.2.2           py311hf62ec03_1
numexpr                   2.8.4           py311h1fcbade_1
numpy                     1.24.3          py311hdab7c0b_1
numpy-base                1.24.3          py311hd01c5d8_1
openssl                   1.1.1u               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.5.3           py311heda8569_0
pip                       23.0.1          py311haa95532_0
python                    3.11.3               h966fe2a_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.11                    2_cp311    conda-forge
pytz                      2022.7          py311haa95532_0
quantlib-python           1.29            py311hacdd394_3    conda-forge
setuptools                67.8.0          py311haa95532_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
sqlite                    3.41.2               h2bbff1b_0
tbb                       2021.8.0             h59b6b97_0
tk                        8.6.12               h2bbff1b_0
tzdata                    2023c                h04d1e81_0
ucrt                      10.0.22621.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vc14_runtime              14.34.31931         h5081d32_16    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.34.31931         hed1258a_16    conda-forge
wheel                     0.38.4          py311haa95532_0
xz                        5.4.2                h8cc25b3_0
zlib                      1.2.13               h8cc25b3_0
zstd                      1.5.5                hd43e919_0
```

Then I tried to change the `ql.UnitedStates()` into `ql.UnitedStates`, like:

```
import QuantLib as ql
date = ql.Date(2,6,2023)

calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE)
date1 = ql.Date(1,6,2023)
date2 = ql.Date(1,6,2024)
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Monthly)
schedual = ql.Schedule(date1,date2,tenor,calendar,ql.Following,
                       ql.Following,ql.DateGeneration.Forward, False)
print(schedual)
```

but it still failed:

> <QuantLib.QuantLib.Schedule; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Schedule
> *' at 0x00000252E21ED110> >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of `UnitedStates` requires a market, as you guessed.

The message you're getting after passing `UnitedStates.NYSE` is not a failure. You did build the schedule object correctly, but it doesn't have a specific string representation to be used when you call `print` so it outputs a generic one.  Use something like this instead:

```
for d in schedual:
    print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I know it is kind of stupid... Just thank you for your time. Your answer helps a lot.